# A coin is tossed 7 times, what's the probability of at least 4 consecutive heads?

Tags: probability

I understand that this question has already been asked multiple times, but I just can't figure out why I'm wrong.
My approach:-

the sample space is $2^7$

now there are $\binom{7}{4}$ ways of partitioning it into groups of 4
, $\binom{7}{5}$ ways into groups of 5, $\binom{7}{6}$ into groups of 6,and 1 way into a group of 7.

Which gives a probability of 0.5. Which agrees with the answers on this site.

However, my book gives the [same answer given here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/a-coin-is-tossed-7-timesthen-the-probability-that-at-least-4-consecutive-heads-appear/), which is $\frac{5}{16}$. I'm unagle to undestand why it's not 0.5. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but what is the actual question? "A coin is tossed 7 times, what's the probability of a heads?" doesn't make sense in English...

Comment: Your calculation answers the question "what's the probability that there are at least $4$ heads?" but the link you give answers a *different* question, "what's the probability that there are at least $4$ *consecutive* heads?"

Comment: To emphasize, an example of a sequence of coin flips who have at least 4 heads while not having at least 4 *consecutive* heads is the sequence HHTTTHH.  There are indeed four heads here... the first, second, sixth, and seventh flips.  Those flips are not considered *consecutive* however because there is a gap in the middle of them.  *Consecutive* flips must all occur immediately one after another with no gaps and no tails between them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I retried it by partitioning the sample space out, so there are 4 sets of 4 heads, 3 sets of 5 heads, 2 sets of 6, and 1 set of 7, which gives 5/64, half of the expected answer, why is this wrong

Comment: There may also be heads that are not consecutive.  For example you could have HHHHTHT.

Comment: Oh. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: For what its worth, rather than breaking into cases based on the exact size of the longest run of heads present, I prefer the approach taken by the link which breaks into cases based on the position of the fourth head in a sequence of heads length at least four.  Also, for what its worth... this question just like your previous failed to mention whether the coin was fair or not which would affect the answer.